# React.lazy() import can't find module if its path is from a constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a contextual sidebar based on the route. The idea is that the container page is the same but the sidebar and some of the content is dynamically loaded.

`React.lazy()` does exactly what I want but for some reason, it only works if I define my module path as an actual string:

```
const SideNav = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./navigation/concepts") // this is fine
);
```

However, I would very much like to make this dynamic so I could define a map of routes to module locations as such:

```
const module_map = {"/docs/concepts" : "./navigation/concepts"};
    
console.log(module_map[this.props.location.pathname] === "./navigation/concepts"); // Just for sanity: this print 'true'
    
const SideNav = React.lazy(() =>
  import(module_map[this.props.location.pathname])
);
```

This results in an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './navigation/concepts'
```

I tried defining the module path first as a constant and even passing it as a property from the parent component but the result is the same.

Any ideas why this is happening and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

use __dirname instead of using relative paths.

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";

const file = `${__dirname}/components/MyComponent`;

const MyComponent = lazy(() => import(file));
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="Loading">
        <MyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, in your code sandbox, `__dirname` resolves to `/src`, providing `/src/components/MyComponent`. In my code, it resolves to an empty string, providing `//components/MyComponent `. The module can't be found even if I manually set the path to the one that it resolves to in your example.

Comment: That could be due to your directory structure and probably webpack configurations. Because as you can see in codesandbox, it works under normal circumstances.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the webpack config - but I bootstrapped my app with the `create-react-app` and there's very little config I can do I think?

Comment: try this solution https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1599 (at the bottom)